# Is there an actual function that "escapes" from zero after an amount of derivatives?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Suppose we have a function $f$ such that for all $i=2,...k: f^{(i)}=0$ but for $i\ge k+1$ we have $f^{(i)}\neq 0$.

Can there be such functions in theory ? and is there an actual function that behaves like this ?

I guess it probably won't be an elementary function or over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: $$f(x) = e^x - \sum_{n = 0}^N \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Comment: Do you mean the derivatives vanish at one point, or everywhere?

Comment: @DanielFischer all possibilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on exactly what you mean:

- If the second derivative of a function is identically zero, then the function is linear - as a consequence, it must have zero derivatives of all orders (except for first order). More generally, if $f^{(i)} \equiv 0$, then it's easy to prove that $f^{(i + 1)} \equiv 0$.
- If you only want the derivative to vanish at a point, then a function like

$$f(x) = e^x - \left(1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \dots + \frac{x^N}{N!}\right)$$

will have zero first, second, and $N$th derivatives at zero, while the $(N+1)$th derivative will be non-zero. This follows from considering the Taylor series for $e^x$ at $0$.

Comment: About the first bullet hole, is it true for all math ? i.e for all fields, maps, etc.